# Low Level Text Output

Tags: macos

I have not done any MACOS programming in several years. However, I now need to test out some algorithms for formatting text as paragraphs. For these tests, I need to be able to display characters with absolute position control.

These tests need to determine where line breaks are to go within a paragraph and the amount of work spacing, while taking into account hyphenation, ligatures, page breaks, kerning and the like.

When I last did such things, I was using the text functions of the CGContext class. Upon returning from my hiatus, I find all of these function are marked "deprecated" in the documentation—which conveniently leaves out what the current acceptable replacement is.

What is the current, approved process for drawing single glyphs on Mac OS?

Functions that deal with formatting strings would defeat the purpose of the academic experiment here.

Comment: Look at the drawing methods of the `NSString` class, e.g. [**`drawAtPoint:withAttributes:`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1533109-drawatpoint?language=objc)

Comment: Thanks, Trying to see if that will work with my oddities.

Comment: Let us know.  Would be useful information.